# Difference between 'from the decay of' and 'from decays of'

Tags: articles

Could you explain the difference in meaning between these two phrases?

1. charged leptons from decays of long-​lived particles
2. charged leptons from the decay of long-​lived particles

From the internet I found many examples of 'A from decays of B' and 'A from the decay of B'. So, I guess both are correct. Then, I wonder how they are different.

Comment: Preference, judgment. I like “the decay of.”

Comment: I haven't seen 'decay' in the plural before. I see 'softwares' quite often, but usually from non-native speakers.

Comment: It looks like this usage is particular to particle physics, where there are multiple stages of decay that a particle can undertake. ["Decays are mediated by one or several fundamental forces."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay)

Comment: As far as I can tell, both are correct, but I'd ordinarily use "decay".  Specifically, the only time I'd use "decays" is when I want to emphasize that different decay modes are involved.